# Angular TypeScript input change event

Tags: typescript, angular, javascript-eventos

Tenho um campo input que é iniciado com um number('.2-2').
Esse input é atualizado quando um campo select modifica o seu valor.
Quando esse campo é modificado, o valor do input numver não obedece a formatação.
O valor default vem por padrão formatado

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col">

  <label class="control-label" for="ID_MONTHLY_VALUE">{{txtMonthl_value}}</label>
  <input type="text" style="text-align:right;font-weight: bold" formControlName="OriginalMonthlyValue" class="form-control input-sm" disabled />
  <!--<input type="text" style="text-align:right;font-weight: bold" [(ngModel)]="OriginalMonthlyValue.value" class="form-control input-sm" />-->

</div>
```

Procuro uma solução. Alguém já passou por esse problema e pode por gentileza me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0):

Vais ter que apontar, directamente, para o formControl dentro do formGroup (pex `formGroup.OriginalMonthlyValue`) e depois fazer `setValue()` nesse form-control.

Uma vez que não estás a usar um ngModel, o modelo associado com o formControl (aka a sua prop de value) nunca foi actualizada automaticamente, então vais ter que o fazer à mão. se!! (no entanto) o input for mudado pelo user - esse setValue é feito automaticamente.

[Mais informaçoes sobre o FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl)